# Is it possible to have multiple composite (aka "many-to-many", ManyToMany) joins that don't make the result set huge

Tags: sql, many-to-many, join, composite

Situation:
Table **book** is associated with one or more **authors** via the **_author_book** table.  It is *also* associated with one or more **genres** via the **_book_genre** table.

When selecting all the books, and all their genres, and all their authors, the number of rows returned is (assume each book has at least one genre and author):

- PROBLEM:
  books.map( |book| book.genres.size * book.authors.size).sum

what I want is:

- DESIRED:
  books.map( |book| [book.genres.size, book.authors.size].max).sum

so given 10 books, each book has 5 genres and 4 authors:

- PROBLEM: 200 rows returned (5 * 4 * 10)
- DESIRED: 50 rows returned ( [5,4].max * 10 )

Example Data:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM book

 id | title
----+---------------------------
 1  | Dune: The Butlerian Jihad
 2  | The Talisman

mysql> SELECT * FROM genre

 id | title
----+-------------
 1  | Military
 2  | Horror
 3  | Thriller
 4  | Sci-Fi
 5  | Fiction
 6  | Speculative

mysql> SELECT * FROM author

 id | title
----+------------------
 1  | Brian Herbert
 2  | Kevin J Anderson
 3  | Stephen King
 4  | Peter Straub

mysql> SELECT * FROM _author_book

 book_id | author_id
---------+-----------
 1       | 1
 1       | 2
 2       | 3
 2       | 4

mysql> SELECT * FROM _book_genre

 book_id | genre_id
---------+-----------
 1       | 1
 1       | 4
 1       | 5
 1       | 6
 2       | 2
 2       | 3
 2       | 5
```

Here's what's wrong:

```
mysql> SELECT book.id AS "book.id", ..., author.fullname AS "author.fullname" FROM book
    -> LEFT JOIN _book_genre ON book.id = _book_genre.book_id
    -> LEFT JOIN genre ON genre.id = _book_genre.genre_id
    -> LEFT JOIN _author_book ON book.id = _author_book.book_id
    -> LEFT JOIN author ON author.id = _author_book.author_id;

 book.id | book.title | genre.id | genre.name  | author.id | author.fullname
---------+------------+----------+-------------+-----------+------------------
 1       | Dune: The… | 1        | Military    | 1         | Brian Herbert
 1       | Dune: The… | 4        | Sci-Fi      | 1         | Brian Herbert
 1       | Dune: The… | 5        | Fiction     | 1         | Brian Herbert
 1       | Dune: The… | 6        | Speculative | 1         | Brian Herbert
---------+------------+----------+-------------+-----------+------------------
 1       | Dune: The… | 1        | Military    | 2         | Kevin J Anderson
 1       | Dune: The… | 4        | Sci-Fi      | 2         | Kevin J Anderson
 1       | Dune: The… | 5        | Fiction     | 2         | Kevin J Anderson
 1       | Dune: The… | 6        | Speculative | 2         | Kevin J Anderson
---------+------------+----------+-------------+-----------+------------------
 2       | The Talis… | 2        | Horror      | 3         | Stephen King
 2       | The Talis… | 3        | Thriller    | 3         | Stephen King
 2       | The Talis… | 5        | Fiction     | 3         | Stephen King
---------+------------+----------+-------------+-----------+------------------
 2       | The Talis… | 2        | Horror      | 4         | Peter Straub
 2       | The Talis… | 3        | Thriller    | 4         | Peter Straub
 2       | The Talis… | 5        | Fiction     | 4         | Peter Straub
```

Hopefully it is clear what the problem is.  The result of the first join, on genre/_book_genre, is being joined with all the author results, resulting in a resultset of 14 rows, when really a result set of only *seven* rows would suffice:

```
 book.id | book.title | genre.id | genre.name  | author.id | author.fullname
---------+------------+----------+-------------+-----------+------------------
 1       | Dune: The… | 1        | Military    | 1         | Brian Herbert
 1       | Dune: The… | 4        | Sci-Fi      | 2         | Kevin J Anderson
 1       | Dune: The… | 5        | Fiction     | 1         | Brian Herbert
 1       | Dune: The… | 6        | Speculative | 2         | Kevin J Anderson
---------+------------+----------+-------------+-----------+------------------
 2       | The Talis… | 2        | Horror      | 3         | Stephen King
 2       | The Talis… | 3        | Thriller    | 4         | Peter Straub
 2       | The Talis… | 5        | Fiction     | 3         | Stephen King
```

(alternatively, the duplicated authors could be NULL values, but if there IS an answer out there, I am assuming it will result in the authors being repeated as above).

My Question: is there some combination of LEFT, RIGHT, INNER, OUTER, A-B-A-B SELECT START that will prevent the many-to-many results from multiplying the number of rows?

Answer (score 1):

Group by and max is what you want.

Comment: I don't see how group by and/or max is going to do any good here.  What do I group by here? genre.id? lose the authors.  author.id? lose the genres.  max will only return one out of a group, which has now already lost some data.

Comment: (back after testing) I tried a bunch of combinations of GROUP BY, even threw in some MAX()'s, though that was half-hearted I'll admit.  I didn't get the "whif" of progress...

Answer (score 0):

Your second result set seems wrong:

```
1       | Dune: The… | 1        | Military    | 1         | Brian Herbert
1       | Dune: The… | 4        | Sci-Fi      | 2         | Kevin J Anderson
```

Can hardly mean what you want. Try wording the resultset how you want it, and you will probably be able to construct the statement you are looking for. Unless you can word it properly, people will have a hard time answering this question, or at least I will.

Comment: I've double checked this, the wording is correct (or at least appropriate).  I've got three groups of data coming back: the books (2), the genres (4 on book one, 3 on book two), and authors (two for each book)

the result set I WANT back (and herein lies my question) only contains 7 rows, not 14.  Consider the case when an item has 20 "categories" and 10 "genres" doing two many-to-many joins will result in 200 rows.  Is there a solution that returns only 20 rows (since that's the minimum needed to display ALL the categories, and the genres would be repeated)

Comment: To me, the above result set means: There is a book called Dune: The..., which is about the military when written by Brian Herbert, and is about Sci-Fi when written by Kevin J Anderson. Why is Military here on the same row as Brian Herbert, and Sci-Fi on the same row as Kevin J anderson?

Comment: The goal is to have ALL the categories and ALL the authors, but only return MAX(COUNT(authors), COUNT(categories)) rows.  The pairing here is arbitrary and incidental, not a desired feature.